# Compile Tensorflow on Platformio ESP-IDF

Tags: tensorflow, esp32, platformio, esp-idf, tflite

How do I compile a project with ESP-IDF (ESP32) on Platformio with Tensorflow? It is an existing project with other libraries and custom code. I just want to add tensorflow micro as any other library, normally with git clone into components.

I tried: cloning these repos

https://github.com/espressif/tflite-micro-esp

https://github.com/espressif/tflite-micro-esp-examples

https://github.com/espressif/tensorflow.git

into the components and lib directories. I tried adding build flags like this:

```
build_flags =
-I $PROJECT_DIR/lib/tensorflow/lite/
-I $PROJECT_DIR/lib/tensorflow/core/
-I $PROJECT_DIR/lib/tensorflow/experimental/
-I $PROJECT_DIR/lib/tensorflow/kernels/
-I $PROJECT_DIR/lib/tensorflow/micro/
-I $PROJECT_DIR/lib/tensorflow/schema/
-I $PROJECT_DIR/lib/tensorflow
-I $PROJECT_DIR/lib/ ...
```

But this seems overkill, and I still can't get it to work. What is the right approach?

When I try to compile, I still get:
`src/myfile.cpp:1:10: fatal error: tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h: No such file or directory`